# Any reference implementation for Netflix turbine with non hystrix server side events

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix, netflix, turbine, resilience4j

I am trying to feed resilence4j (circuit breaker) based events to turbine stream monitor. we have turbine stream aggregator that is already consuming several hystrix streams from bunch of micro services. New microservices are all being written based on resilence4j and we wanted to feed the Server side events that resilence4j emits to feed to turbine so that we can collectively look at all of them.

According to the documentation of turbine https://github.com/Netflix/Turbine/wiki , any Key value pair JSON can be aggregated as long as they emit the events of Server side event(SSE) type. I am finding it hard to implement that. Also explored spring cloud flavor of turbine.

The problem I see is, turbine is selectively looking for hystrix based SSE data.  Any suggestions or thoughts on how to proceed or it is not even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the documentation has the correct details. turbine expects type, name and group part of the stream it seems. once we add the following KV pairs to the SSE steam. core turbine observed the stream.

```
data: {"type":"circuitbreaker","name":"resilence4j","group":"wrench","current_time":"2019-11-02T15:04:54.241Z"... other values}
```